# Composer 2.3.0 dropped support for PHP less than 7.2.5 and you are running 7.1.33

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Facing issue after downgrade the PHP version with updated version of composer,
I am trying to doing **upgrade PHP or use Composer 2.2 LTS via "composer self-update --2.2** which option is given by CMD.

I tried myself with downgrade the PHP version using the Command of brew but I tried to get the solution for composer, Either it's possible to downgrade or upgrade the version of composer same like PHP.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. The recommendation you got was to run `composer self-update --2.2` which will downgrade composer to 2.2 which is a version which works with your version of PHP

Comment: Are you actually still running PHP 7.1? That has been out of support for over 3 years: https://www.php.net/eol.php. If you're looking to update Composer to 2.3, you'll need to upgrade PHP too. Also, downgrading PHP with `brew` will not work, as all versions < 7.4 have been removed, so you likely won't be able to install that at all. Even 8.0 is deprecated, meaning it will eventually be removed (I think within a year?). Either way, aim for PHP 8.1+ if you can.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing right now? How is this question related to Laravel?